# Cannot set session in rspec test (ruby jets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have and small project using ruby Jets `3.0.22` and I'm trying to test a function inside a controller using `rspec`. The issue is that the function uses a session variable set by another controller and I can't set it inside the test so it is always `nil`.

The function that I'm trying to test is this:

```rb
def favorite

 favorite = data.items.detect { |item| item['val']['id'] == params[:id] }

 unless favorite.blank? || (@song.present? && session[:user].songs.exists?(@song.id))
   session[:user].songs << (@song || Song.create!(name: favorite['track']['name'],
                                                         id: favorite['track']['id']))
   end

  render json: { favorite: favorite.present? }, status: 200
end
```

the `session[:user]` is always `nil`

This is the test that I'm trying to do

```rb
it 'works' do
 get '/favorite/', params: { search_term: :search_term }
 expect(response.status).to eq 200
end
```

I tried to set the `session` before the test but the object is nil:

```rb
request.session['user'] = create(:user) # request doesn't have session
session[:user] = create(:user) # session is nil 
 # pass as parameter of the request
get '/favorite/', params: { search_term: :search_term }, session: {user: create(:user)}
```

versions:

- Rspec `3.10`
- Ruby `2.7.4p191`
- Jets `3.0.22`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your spec file is a controller spec, because for controller specs rspec adds helper like `session` for you.

If your want to access the session outside the controller spec you can try adding `include ::RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup` which should suffice (Not tested).